# Multiple Social Logins with spring

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google

I have multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters in my webapp one for each part of the app and need to have multiple "login with FB/Google" buttons with different behaviours.

I have been trying to configure multiple SpringSocialConfigurers one per each WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but this doesn't seem to work as only one gets used at a time.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ASecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

final EventRegistrationAuthenticationHandler authHandler = new EventRegistrationAuthenticationHandler();
final SpringSocialConfigurer socialSecurityConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
socialSecurityConfigurer.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
socialSecurityConfigurer.postLoginUrl("/asd");
```

And

```
@Configuration
@Order(3)
public static class BSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

final SpringSocialConfigurer socialSecurityConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
socialSecurityConfigurer.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
socialSecurityConfigurer.postLoginUrl("/gogogoogogo");
```

Comment: Where does `SpringSocialConfigurer` come from (I can't see it in spring-social-core)?

Comment: org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer

Comment: That's this thing: https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security? I don't know much about that, but I think you are going to have to show more code anyway, since the snippets we have don't really explain what you did fully.